# How to place FB.login popup in the middle in FF

Tags: facebook

Got problem with launching `FB.login()`, it works well. FB.login opens popup-window with requesting LoginPassword. Everything is fine, but in Opera, IE popupwindow opens in the center and in FF - on the right side like smbody puts float:right.
IDK how to fix this so asking here.

As a result question: how make this popup appears in the middle of the screen in Firefox?

**P.S** I need popup, so please don't suggest using samewindow methods with redirect_uri

Comment: Are u using some javascript/asp.net ?